# Quadratic forms in quadratic fields

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

Can we find any reference or introductory notes on the topic quadratic forms in quadratic fields?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The classic reference is *Rational Quadratic Forms* by J. W. S. Cassels, but I'm not sure it discusses quadratic fields.

Comment: Thank you. I will find out

Answer (score 1):

Let $K=\mathbb Q( (-1+\sqrt(1-4c))/2 )$ be a number field. $K$ is a quadratic number field, and the norm form of $K$ is $N=x^2+xy+cy^2$. This is the simplest norm form. Suppose $jk=c$. Then $jx^2+xy+k^2$ is another representable norm form of $K$. In particular, if $h$ is the class number of $K$, then there are exactly $(h-1)/2$ unique representable norm forms of $K$ is $h$ is odd. The class numbers of quadratic fields are extensively studied and I would recommend starting there.

Comment: I tried an answer, see if you agree with it

Answer (score 1):

There is what I know about this :

Let $d \in \mathbb{Z}_{<0}$ and $K =\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$.

For each ideal class $c \in C_K$ pick a representative ideal $I_c$, a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$ so $I_c = u_c \mathbb{Z}+v_c \mathbb{Z}$.

Look at the positive definite integer valued quadratic form $$q_{I_c}(n,m) = N(u_cn+v_cm)= |u_cn+v_cm|^2=|u_c|^2n^2+2Re(u_c\overline{v_c})nm+|v_c|^2m^2$$

Then $N(I_c)$ is the $\gcd$ of the values taken by the $N(\alpha), \alpha \in I_c$ so $$Q_c(n,m) = \frac{q_{I_c}(n,m)}{N(I_c)}$$ is a primitive integer valued binary quadratic form.

Let $\widehat{Q_c} = \{ Q_c \circ \gamma, \gamma\in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})\}$ the class of $\mathbb{Z}$-equivalent quadratic forms. Then $\widehat{Q_c}$ depends only on $c$.

Also its discriminant doesn't depend on $c$ (up to sign it is the area of the fundamental domain of the lattice $\frac{u_c\mathbb{Z}+v_c \mathbb{Z}}{N(I_c)^{1/2}}$) so $\Delta(Q_c) = \Delta(Q_{(1)}) = \Delta_K$ which is a negative integer and a [fundamental discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_discriminant).

The complex conjugaison descends to an $Aut(C_K)$ and
$\widehat{Q_c} = \widehat{Q_{c_2}}$ iff $c = c_2$ or $c = \overline{c_2}$ .

All the primitive positive definite integer valued binary quadratic forms of discriminant $\Delta_K$ arise this way ($q$ is positive definite means $q = q_L$ for some lattice in $O_F$ with $F$ a quadratic imaginary number field, and if $L$ is not a fractional ideal then $q_L = q_{L O_F} \circ \beta$ for some $\beta \in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ so $q_L$ is not primitive).

For non-primitive positive definite quadratic forms we'd probably develop something similar in an order of a quadratic field.

I'm not sure how to adapt all this to non-positive definite quadratic forms.

Comment: For ideal classes, there should be $h$ total, where $h$ is the class number of $K$. Except for the principal ideal class, there are $(h-1)/2$ different ideal classes, because any two can be conjugate and have the same representative ideal. This is also the number of binary quadratic forms you are looking for.

Comment: Now on the other hand, determining $I_c$ seems to be a difficult problem in general, and it is one I am currently trying to solve for cyclotomic fields $K$. But cyclotomic fields are of much more magnitude difficult to solve than quadratic fields. The hardness of this problem will depend on the class number $h$ of $K$. The larger, the more difficult.

Comment: @J.Linne In quadratic fields, for prime ideals thus for all ideals : $I \overline{I}$ is a principal ideal so $\overline{c} = c^{-1}$ and the number of quadratic forms is then $a+ \frac{h-a}{2}$ where $a = \# \{ c \in C_K, c^2 = (1)\}$. If $h= |C_K|$ is odd then $a=1$, otherwise $a = 2^n$ where $C_K \cong G \times G_2$ where $|G| $ is odd and $G_2$ is a product of $n$ cyclic groups of order a power of $2$.